# How can I use previously built jars in a multi-module maven project?

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I have [this maven multi-module project](https://github.com/ICIJ/datashare) :

```
ModuleA
  src
  pom.xml
  target
    ModuleA-with-dependencies-shaded.jar (version 4.1 of lucene relocated)
ModuleB
  src
  pom.xml
  target
    ModuleB-with-dependencies.jar (version 7.5.0 of lucene)
ModuleDist
  assembly
    all.xml
  pom.xml (shaded plugin for jar + assembly for Docker)
```

The dist pom plugins are configured like this :

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <shadedClassifierName>all</shadedClassifierName>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <transformers>
                        <!--remove models from jar see mitie -->
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.DontIncludeResourceTransformer">
                            <resource>.dat</resource>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <artifactSet>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>log4j:log4j:jar:</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    </artifactSet>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <id>make-dist</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/assembly/all.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And the assembly all.xml :

```
<assembly>
    <id>all</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

As the `ModuleA` is having a transitive dependency on `lucene 4.1` (but relocated so it won't clash with moduleB) and `ModuleB` is having a transitive dependency on `lucene 7.5.0`, I'd like to use the **previously built** and shaded jar of `ModuleA` in the maven shaded plugin of `ModuleDist` (because if I relocate lucene in `ModuleDist` it is relocating all lucene classes).

How could I do that ?
or is there another way of doing this ?

Comment: The shaded jar can be addressed by the same coordinates as the module it is done but you have to add `<classifier>shaded</classifier>` ...

Comment: thank you @khmarbaise, we used another classifier name but that's what we did.

Answer (score 1):

To add all your jars of the runtime dependencies to the assembly, add something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<assembly>
...
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
       <unpack>false</unpack>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Take a look at the assembly plugin [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) for more details.
A working example can be found [here](https://github.com/1and1/snmpman) (no shading used).

My personal experience is that it's better to only have one final module that assembles all stuff. This way the shader doesn't have to disassemble and assembler everything over and over.

Shading is a big problem when using Jackson and Log4j2 because it breaks some extension lookup mechanisms that expect everything to be in a separate jar. I recommend not using it anymore.

Comment: Yeah but then you'll end with several jars that may be loaded in different order, and the result will be different function of the order. I wanted to end with a fixed jar

Comment: It's up to your preference: The loading order is defined by the classpath. If you have a shaded jar, possible collisions will be 'resolved' by the shader (=usually not resolved). Is the dependencySets-part working for you?

Comment: yes we used dependency set before making the docker image build. But as we had to remove NLP models and to have a jar ready before the docker assembly we've chosen to use the shade plugin that broke the final jar. We ended up with 2 assemblies, and chaining them for the final docker folder.

Comment: Good :)! If this solved your problem, It would be nice if you marked the question as resolved.

Comment: it's not to make the assembly that solved the issue (as i told you we were doing this before having to build the docker assembly) it's the idea to make two assemblies with the second taking the deliverables of the previous one. I voted up your answer but I will explicit what we did in another post